# Why do my ValueEventListener have delayed effect?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When i first click the button, the value of `pass` variable is `null`
When i click it for the second time and change the value of `edit1`, the `pass` value is the value of the `edit1` from the first click 
Why is that?
This is my code

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("user").child(edit1.getText().toString()).child("password");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            pass = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you use `pass`, but most likely that is outside of `onDataChange`. You're seeing the effects of the fact that `onDataChange` is called asynchronously, which means the code *inside* `onDataChange` is invoked *after* the code *after* it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519